# Strings in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

My array looks like this:

```
var imagetitle = new Array()
imagetitle[0] = "One two tree";
imagetitle[1] = "Zero One seven abc";
imagetitle[2] = "qwe qwe qwe";
imagetitle[3] = "rerere erere weqwe";
```

Imagetitle is used as title in HTML later. Problem is that when I use it like this, It display only 1st word of string, not full string.

```
function showimage() {
var div_sa_slikom = document.createElement("div");
div_sa_slikom.innerHTML = "<a href="+imagetarget[i_image]+" title="+imagetitle[i_image]+" target='_parent'><img style='border:none;' src="+imageurl[i_image]+" border='0' title="+imagetitle[i_image]+" alt="+imagetitle[i_image]+" /></a>";
var container = document.getElementById("slike_rotator");
container.appendChild(div_sa_slikom);
}
```

Comment: How are you setting the title?

Comment: You'll have to show us the part where you use it - there's nothing wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: You're missing a semi colon in the above - doubt that's related though; probably just a typo in the question. var imagetitle = new Array();

Comment: Show the code where you call `imagetitle`

Comment: You didn't initialize `i_image` !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the HTML you're building is missing quotes.

You're building

```
title=One two tree
```

instead of

```
title="One two tree"
```

Replace your function with

```
function showimage() {
   var div_sa_slikom = document.createElement("div");
   div_sa_slikom.innerHTML = '<a href="'+imagetarget[i_image]+'" title="'+imagetitle[i_image]+'" target="_parent">'
       + '<img style="border:none;" src="'+imageurl[i_image]+'" border=0 title="'+imagetitle[i_image]+'" alt="'+imagetitle[i_image]+'">'
       + '</a>';
   var container = document.getElementById("slike_rotator");
   container.appendChild(div_sa_slikom);
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't fix all quotes. I edited my answer with the complete function.